# How do I separate integers that contain commas from a text file using Strtol in C programming?

Tags: c, string, parsing

There are approximately 150,000 numbers in a text file. These numbers consist of one line. I'm supposed to seperate these by commas. But I'm not allowed to use a fixed-size array. I thought about seperating the numbers I got by the strtol function. But I couldn't find how I can.

[image]

Comment: Hint: One of the arguments to `strtol()` is a pointer that is set to the end of the leading section of the string that was converted to a number. In other words, a comma. Use taht in a loop.

Comment: Can you be specific on what you mean by 'not allowed to use fixed-size array' ?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to `strtol` (and similar functions) is the address of a `char*` variable:

```
long strtol(const char* str, char** endptr, int base);
```

If the argument is not NULL, it must point to a `char*`, which will be filled in with the address of the first character in `str` not consumed by `strtol`. In the case of comma-separated numbers, this will be the address of the comma (except in the case of the last number in the list).

You can easily use that to read all the  numbers in sequence:

```
char* end = ",";
for (const char* p = buffer; *end == ','; p = end + 1) {
  long number = strtol(p, &end, 0);
  if (end == p) break;   /* There was no number */
  /* check for other errors */
  /* store the number in a dynamic array */
}
if (*end != '\n' && *end != '\0') {
  /* Input was not as expected. Signal error */
}
```

The `for` loop starts a pointer at the first character in the string, and checks to make sure that the previous number was terminated with a comma. (We initialise the `end` pointer to point at a comma so that this test works on the first iteration.) At the end of the loop, it moves `p` over the terminator (whatever it was) and continues.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you mean by *I'm not allowed to use a fixed-size array*: let's assume you are supposed to allocate the array for the values and make no assumptions about the maximum number of items.

- you should not try and read the file into an array of `char`, with `fgets()` or `fwrite()`, because this array would need to be very large and there is no way to tell in advance how large to allocate it. Hence `strtol()` is not the right tool.
- a simpler alternative is to read the text file one byte at a time and compute the numbers on the fly, or use `fscanf()`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* read all numbers separated by `,` into an allocated array.
   *ptr -> pointer to the allocated array
   *psize -> allocated size of the array
   return value: number of values read
*/
int read_numbers(FILE *fp, int **ptr, int *psize) {
    int *array;
    int n, size;
    int num;

    *ptr = array = NULL;
    *psize = size = n = 0;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d,", &num) == 1) {
        if (n == size) {
            /* reallocate array by the golden ratio */
            size = size + (size / 2) + (size / 8) + 16;
            array = realloc(array, sizeof(*array) * size);
            if (array == NULL) {
                free(*ptr);
                *ptr = NULL;
                *psize = 0;
                return -1;   /* not enough memory */
            }
            *ptr = array;
            *psize = size;
        }
        array[n++] = num;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick hint for people looking how to use strtol with different separators. Here is version with comma:

```
char * pEnd;

    par1=strtol(txt+3,&pEnd,16);
    if (*pEnd==',') pEnd++;
    par2=strtol(pEnd,&pEnd,16);
```

Without this "trick" separator is "*space*" and "*comma*" is stopper.